# Question about Uniform Norm

Tags: real-analysis

The question is: let $t:\left \{ 1,...,n \right \}\rightarrow\left \{ 1,...,n \right \}$. Given the fact that $f(\mathbf{x}) = \left \| \mathbf{x} \right \|_\infty $ is continuous then show that the function $g: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,  $g(\mathbf{x})=\mathrm{max}\left \{ |x_1-x_{t(1)}|^2,...,|x_n-x_{t(n)}|^2 \right \}$ is continuous. Can someone give me some hint? I really do not know how to get start with. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

HINT : for each $1 \leq i \leq n$, $|x_i - x_{t(i)}|^2 \leq |x_i|^2 + |x_{t(i)}|^2 \leq 2f(x)^2$. Therefore, taking the maximum, $g(x) \leq 2f(x)^2$ for all $x$.

Therefore, for any two points $x,y$, $|g(x)-g(y)| \leq 2|f(x)^2 - f(y)^2|$, and $f(x)^2$ is a continuous function, since $f(x)$ is a continuous function. Use this to given an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument for the continuity of $g$.

Comment: Thanks, it is very helpful!

Comment: By the way, do you know why $||x||_{\infty}$ is continuous? You were asked to assume it, but I think it is easy, so you should know.